# Log when Google Docs text changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am experimenting with the end-to-end latency of Google Docs: how long it takes for one user's edits to show up for other users. To measure this, I need a way to detect when the text in a Google Doc changes. Ideally, each change would be logged to the console.

This used to be possible by [watching the raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677854/google-docs-access-text-changes-realtime), but Google Docs switched to using their own Canvas in ~2021. I have also tried some 2022-era tricks to switch it to legacy HTML mode ([`window._docs_force_html_by_ext = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996235/16782898); installing Grammarly extension) but they no longer seem to work.

Other things I've tried:

- Google Apps Script: There is no [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers) for watching changes to a Google Doc (only a Sheet). The more powerful APIs runs server-side and so wouldn't work for my user-to-user measurements.
- Accessibility -> Live Edits: This works (edits show up in an HTML side bar), but on a substantial delay. I believe it waits until the other user "stops typing" before showing an edit.

Comment: It is true that there is currently no onEdit trigger at the moment on Google Docs, although I believe it has already been [raised up as a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232821178) so that it may hopefully be updated.

Comment: And just to clarify, your main goal is to check for the time from when a user types a character on Google Docs, to when it shows up on another user's end? You have mentioned that in one of the workarounds you've found, it waits until a user "stops typing" for the function to run, and does not detect the text change in real time.

Comment: @MicTest Correct. The Live Edits appear to wait 5 seconds after the user stops interacting or moves the cursor, but I would prefer to measure end-to-end latency with <1 second error.

Comment: Got it. In that case, for now you can try to upvote or +1 the existing feature request so that the people at Google who are working on it will be notified. But at the moment, I believe there is no feasible workaround for your specific use case to get real-time latency on Google Docs edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Using a function like Puppeteer's [evaluateOnNewDocument](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluateonnewdocument), inject the following code before the page is loaded:

```js
window._docs_annotate_canvas_by_ext = "<extension ID>";
```

Here `<extension ID>` must be the ID of a Chrome extension that is whitelisted to work with Google Docs. You can found a list of valid IDs by searching for `i8d=` in [the code](https://docs.google.com/static/document/client/js/2390069698-client_js_prod_kix_core__en_gb.js). ([Source](https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils/issues/10#issuecomment-1537490149))

2. Now Google Docs will use the same Canvas-based renderer, but it will also add SVG elements to the DOM, whose `aria-label` attribute contains the text. I believe it is "drawing" rects to indicate where snippets of text are.
   The SVG elements are deep under the `docs-editor-container` div, near the actual `<canvas>` element.
3. To detect text changes, use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver):

```js
const contentRoot = document.querySelector(".kix-rotatingtilemanager-content");
new MutationObserver(onMutation).observe(
    contentRoot,
    {subtree: true, childList: true}
);
```

Empirically, when the text changes, Google Docs will remove an old node and add a new one with the updated `aria-label`. Text with different inline formats will be split across multiple nodes; header-formatted text doesn't show up at all; and nodes also appear/disappear as text is scrolled into/out of view. This is my best attempt at processing it:

```js
function onMutation(mutationList) {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length === 0) continue;
    if (mutation.removedNodes.length === 0) {
      // It may have been scrolled into view - not actually new text.
      continue;
    }
    
    let after = "";
    for (const added of mutation.addedNodes) {
      after += added.ariaLabel ?? "";
    }

    let before = "";
    for (const removed of mutation.removedNodes) {
      before += removed.ariaLabel ?? "";
    }

    if (after !== before) {
        // Text changed from "before" to "after"...
    }
  }
}
```